# Find first day and last day of previous week in SSIS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have checked in SQL and get values of first day and last day of previous week, but I want in SSIS expression.

I tried in SQL script

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),0) AS DATE) --First day of previous week
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6) AS DATE) --Last day of previous week
```

Comment: Is the issue solved? Have you tried the suggestions below?

Answer (score 3):

I believe SSIS uses the same expressions as SSRS.

First Day of Previous week would be:

```
=DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay,dateadd("d",-7,Today),0,0)+1,dateadd("d",-7,Today))
```

Last Day of Previous week would be:

```
=dateadd("d", 6, DateAdd("d",-DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay,dateadd("d",-7,Today),0,0)+1,dateadd("d",-7,Today)))
```

The above is based on a Sunday start and Saturday ending week.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expressions within derived columns:

*First day of previous week*

```
DATEADD("wk",DATEDIFF("wk",7,GETDATE()),0)
```

*Last day of previous week*

```
DATEADD("wk",DATEDIFF("wk",7,GETDATE()),6)
```

**References**

- [DATEADD (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/dateadd-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)